# ServiceStack.Redis v3 and multiple hosts - recommended architecture

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis, servicestack-bsd

We are experiencing an issue where multiple instances of `RedisMqServer` are tripping up over each other - stopping one server stops the others. Clearly the way we have implemented this is wrong, but I can't identify how one is supposed to use `RedisMqServer` in this situation.

Our infrastructure consists of:

- Two Redis servers in a master/slave configuration
- Two load-balanced API instances (referred to as 'API A' below)
- Two load-balanced API instances (referred to as 'API B' below)

API A and B are two independent applications which use ServiceStack.Redis's `RedisMqServer` to send both synchronous and asynchronous messages to each other. We are using the open source v3 revision of ServiceStack.

Both APIs have a `RedisMqServer` configured, as asynchronous communication happens in both directions.

When `RedisMqServer` is disposed, it sends a `STOP` message on the `mq:topic:in` channel, which results in the server unsubscribing from all channels and therefore stopping it from servicing requests.

However because this channel is being used by both API A and API B, stopping either one ends up stopping the other.

Is one supposed to use a single Redis server instance per instance of `RedisMqServer`?

Of note, each API is only connecting to a single Redis server at any point in time. The slave server is only connected to if the master becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior with Redis MQ in v3, but the latest `RedisMqServer` in v4 works as expected and only stops the `RedisMqServer` instance that was disposed.

Comment: That's a pity, but I appreciate the confirmation that I haven't just made a trivial architectural mistake. Thanks.